# Razor output in Json object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i return the output of Razor in a Json object? For example, i want to do something like this:

```
ActionResult res = PartialView(new Home("Text"));
res.ExecuteResult();
```

And then take whatever the previous code produces and put it into another model and pass the model to the action method's PartialView() helper.

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String

Comment: And why won't you simply return [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.108).aspx) using [`Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.108).aspx) method?

Comment: @PLB looks like OP wants to stream rendered HTML packed in JSON response.

Comment: No i want to use the templating system that Razor provides and get the result of applying a model to this template.

Comment: I misunderstood question. Sorry for noise. :)

Comment: No worries, Alexei Levenkov got it...!!